# How to display a TextView when Recycler View is empty?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I would like to display a textView when my RecyclerView is empty.
I prepared this function but it doesn't work. I believe I should get the list from RecyclerView but I don't really know how.
I am in a fragment.

XML:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_list" />

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_no_records"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/nothing_to_display"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Fragment:

```
private fun displayList() {

    val list = listOf<Shoe>()
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        binding.recyclerViewList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.tvNoRecords.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        binding.recyclerViewList.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.tvNoRecords.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Adding the shoe (in ViewModel):

```
fun addShoe(shoe: Shoe) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.addShoes(shoe)
        }
    }
```

Many thanks,
Anna

Comment: looks like you have it the wrong way around. when `list.isEmpty()` I think you want the `else` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions are inverted. When list is empty you are showing recyclerView and vice versa. Simply use a not check.
Consider below:

```
private fun displayList() {

    val list = listOf<Shoe>()
    if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
        binding.recyclerViewList.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        binding.tvNoRecords.visibility = View.GONE
    } else {
        binding.recyclerViewList.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.tvNoRecords.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, now I only see the message- even when I add items to the recyclerView :(

Comment: Please share the code of how and where you are adding the items.

Comment: I add them through Room. Sorry I am quite a noobie

Comment: @AnnaB if that is literally your function that you use then it's always like that obviously because you create an empty list and then check if that list is empty. Instead of creating a new list you should check the actually list's size. I haven't worked with Room myself yet, but I suppose somewhere in your code you pass the data to an Adapter. There would be a spot to check the size and call your function to hide and show the views

Comment: Yeah like @IvoBeckers said the list will always be empty because there is no item added yet. So for this to work out, after you are calling the addShoe() function, you can return the data or however your functionality seem to be and check after that whether the list is empty or not